# Subscribing to a Selector returns Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, subscription

I have a selector that feeds info to a child. The selector works and the child component is built properly however, I wanted to subscribe to the selector in the parent component and use the information for a different task but the subscribe returns an undefined value. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Code:

```
size: any;
mySubscription: Subscription;

constructor(
    private AppStore: Store<Store.NewState>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
       this.position$ = this.AppStore.select(positionSelectors.selectPositionState);
       if (!this.position$ === undefined) {
         this.mySubscription = this.position$.subscribe((resp) => {
         this.size = Object.keys(resp).length;
        } );
        this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
       }
  }
```

So I am trying to get the length of the response however, nothing makes it past the conditional. If I remove it I get a bunch of errors stating that the Object is undefined.
The specific error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Comment: Try:  `if (this.position$ !== undefined) {...}`

Comment: You try to create a subscription... but you unsubsribe immediately on it. Try to unsubsribe on your ngOnDestroy OR use rxjs method, such as take(x)

Comment: both work but the value of position is undefined and that's the problem. Why is that my selector works but the subscribe returns an undefined value?

Answer (score 0):

Root Cause,

> Negation before !this.position$ which becomes false then you are strictly
>   checking it with undefined which will never go inside if block, because it always evaluate it to false

As Comment Suggested, please use ngOnInit & ngOnDestroy life cycle, Please check below code snippet

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.position$ = this.AppStore.select(positionSelectors.selectPositionState);
  if(!this.position$) this.mySubscription = this.position$.subscribe(() => console.log("Logic Here"));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this.mySubscription) this.mySubscription.unSubscribe();
}
```

Comment: As mentioned above this isn't the problem. If you remove the conditional it still throws the same error. I've fixed the bad practice. However, The root of the problem is as the error message states...The value after subscribing is undefined.

Comment: @Haq.H did you try to look if the problem is not the initial state which is emit ?

Comment: Yes, there is not problem with the initial state, I tested the output for the selector and it works fine. The issue is with my subscription but I can't figure out where.

Comment: @Haq.H If possible can you please share code for your selector & state

Comment: The Selector and State work fine. I use the that selector to send info to the child and it's working fine as mentioned in the original question.